# What scientific constraints will the Nova C IM-1 mission have?

Tags: lunar-landing, scientific-data, im-1, nova-c, intuitive-machine

The [IM-1 mission](https://www.intuitivemachines.com/im-1) flipped over during its landing attempt. Luckily there still is a decent connection with the spacecraft.

From what I have seen, some things that they planned such as using an eagleCAM to record the landing couldn’t deploy, which limited the scientific data about how the moon dust interacts with the engine exhaust.

Which scientific experiments cannot complete their mission or have only a limited use because the probe flipped?

Comment: At this point, we don't know. Intuitive Machines has been rather non-transparent and borderline deceptive in their communication so far, so right now, all we can do is wait and guess.

Comment: During the press conference on February 23rd, Intuitive Machines CEO Steve Altemus  said that all of the science payloads are exposed. Not all antennas are available which limits data rate, but they think it should be enough. Eagle cam did not fire during landing but they plan to use it to get a shot of the lander orientation. Joel Kearns of  NASA was somewhat less certain about the NASA payloads, saying they still had to do assessments to see if any measurements are not possible in the new orientation. And it may be harder for orbiting spacecraft to get a reflection from the laser array.

Comment: @Dragongeek what do you consider them to have said that's deceptive (as opposed to just mistaken)? The press conference seemed quite forthcoming especially compared to say, SpaceX.

Comment: @OrganicMarble While mistakes are obviously fine, they claimed that it was "upright" on the Moon during their livestream, and while they later walked this back (*after* the stock market closed), they should've done so much sooner. Additionally, while this may not be directly IM's fault (rather NASA's) this tweet https://twitter.com/NASA/status/1761185745241313777 is rather deceptive because this image is easy to interpret as being from the lander *on* the moon. I saw multiple news outlets publishing this story, and using this image as "photo from the surface".

Comment: @OrganicMarble It might also be that I'm just holding them to a different standard and that I'm spoiled from the excellent communication and frequent updates we got from the other CLPS Astrobotic landing attempt. Also, unlike SpaceX, they are a publicly traded company (which I think is a mistake, but I digress) which means that they have a responsibility to keep the shareholders and the public informed about what they're doing or, viewed pessimistically, can influence the market and their valuation by strategically releasing or not releasing bad news.

Comment: @Dragongeek the press release about the lander dying was...interestingly written, I'll agree. Blah blah blah, good news, good news, oh by the way, it's gonna die tomorrow.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - in a tweet today Intuitive Machines referred to the lander as a "he".  _"capturing this image approximately 30 meters above the lunar surface while **his** main engine throttled"_. I realize there have been tweets from rovers etc. for consumption by the general public which presumably enjoys personifying machinery. But in this case it's a tweet from IM regarding their lander. Just seems odd referring to it as a person. Of course airplanes and ships being referred to as "she" is nothing new, but somehow this seems a little different. Or maybe I am just hopelessly out of date.